# If $E_n = (-1 + \sin\frac{1}{2n}, 1 - \sin\frac{1}{2n} )$, then what would $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ be equal to?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $E_n = (-1 + \sin\frac{1}{2n}, 1 - \sin\frac{1}{2n} )$, then what would $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ be equal to? Would it equal the interval (-1, 1)?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\sin \frac{1}{2n}$ starts at $\sin \frac{1}{2}$ and decreases monotonically to zero, so $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq \cdots$.

Comment: I think you mean that it starts at $\sin(½)$